# Simplifying the second moment of PDF

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose I have a continuous PDF $f(x)$ such that $x>0$ and $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = 1$ .

Given the second moment about $0$ is $$E[X^2]=\int_0^\infty x^2f(x)\,dx$$

I try to simplify this using the product rule:

$g(x)=x^2$

$g'(x)=2x$

$h(x)=\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$

$h'(x)=f(x)$

Hence:

$$E[X^2]=x^2\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx-\int_0^\infty 2x\left(\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx\right) \,dx$$

But because $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = 1$ this just simplifies to $x^2-\int_0^\infty 2x\,dx = 0$

Which isn't right. Am I doing something completely wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the indefinite integral$$\int hg=h\int g-\int\left(h'\int g\right)+C$$If we take $\int g=G$, we have$$\int hg=hG-\int h'G+C$$

So when you apply the limits, you get$$\int_a^b hg=h(b)G(b)-h(a)G(a)-\int_a^bh'G$$In your case, $h(x)=x^2,g(x)=f(x)$ so$$\int_0^\infty x^2f(x)=\left[x^2\int f(x)\right]\Big|_{\text{at }x=\infty}-\left[x^2\int f(x)\right]\Big|_{\text{at }x=0}-\int_0^\infty\left(2x\int f(x)\right)$$

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: @AlexAd If you are satisfied with my answer, consider accepting it by clicking the tick-mark button next to my answer.